# What do I need to change in my code that uses ColorBox?

Tags: javascript, 10

I get the following errors and I am unable to understand why.

```
drupal.js?v=10.1.6:64 Uncaught TypeError: a(...).colorbox is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (nacolorbox.js:19:11)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:383:1)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:205:1)
    at Object.attach (nacolorbox.js:6:41)
    at drupal.js?v=10.1.6:166:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=10.1.6:162:34)
    at big_pipe.js?v=10.1.6:138:10
    at big_pipe.js?v=10.1.6:169:3
drupal.js?v=10.1.6:64 Uncaught TypeError: a(...).colorbox is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (nacolorbox.js:19:11)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:383:1)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:205:1)
    at Object.attach (nacolorbox.js:6:41)
    at drupal.js?v=10.1.6:166:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=10.1.6:162:34)
    at drupal.init.js?v=10.1.6:32:12
    at HTMLDocument.listener (drupal.init.js?v=10.1.6:20:7)
drupal.js?v=10.1.6:64 Uncaught TypeError: a(...).colorbox is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (nacolorbox.js:19:11)
    at Function.each (jquery.js:383:1)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.js:205:1)
    at Object.attach (nacolorbox.js:6:41)
    at drupal.js?v=10.1.6:166:24
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Drupal.attachBehaviors (drupal.js?v=10.1.6:162:34)
    at success (ajax.js?v=10.1.6:1800:20)
    at l (loadjs.min.js?v=4.2.0:1:217)
    at loadjs.min.js?v=4.2.0:1:1556
```

There are 3 calls to the Colorbox function on the page, but each error looks slightly different. I am not sure if that's relevant.

My code calling it is the following.

```js
import jQuery from 'jquery';

(($) => {
  Drupal.behaviors.naColorbox = {
    attach(context) {
      $('.block--collapsible', context).each((index, element) => {
        const content = $(element).find('.block--collapsible__content');
        let height = '92%';
        try {
          height = `${parseInt($(window).height() * 0.92, 10)}px`;
        } catch (ex) {
          // do nothing
        }
        $(element).colorbox({
          inline: true,
          href: content,
          width: '92%',
          height,
          maxWidth: '960px',
          maxHeight: '720px',
          scrolling: true,
        });
      });
    },
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Looking at the page's source, with JavaScript not aggregated, I see this.

```html
<script src="/modules/contrib/colorbox/js/colorbox.js?v=10.1.6"></script>
<script src="/libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js?v=10.1.6"></script>
<script src="/modules/contrib/colorbox_inline/js/colorbox_inline.js?s46bqs"></script>
<!-- omissis -->
<script src="/modules/contrib/colorbox_load/js/colorbox_load.js?s46bqs"></script>
<!-- omissis -->
<script src="/themes/custom/my_theme/dist/js/00-base/06-colorbox/nacolorbox.js?s46bqs"></script>
```

I just upgraded to Drupal 10.1.6 and I am using Colorbox 2.0.1.

What am I missing? It seems everything is installed, but I can't make this work.

Comment: Did you check that /libraries/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js is reachable? Also you probably want to use `once` to make sure the behaviours aren’t attached to the same elements multiple times